# htop - more space for CPUs when many CPUs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, htop

I like htop a lot, with fewer CPUs there is a bar next to each CPU showing how much it is utilised, however at 127 CPUs the usage bar is gone... I would like to know how to spread the CPUs over the whole screen, or at least over more than 8 rows, so that the usage bar reappears. How to do it?

[image: htop example]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F2</kbd> to get to the setup menu. Navigate to "Header layout" and select fewer columns.

Comment: where is "header layout"?

Comment: left hand of the screen, under "Categories"

Comment: interesting, i guess we have a different version of htop

Comment: that might very well be!